# Dropbox Error executing HTTP request: SSL connect error

Tags: php, ssl, curl, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

I've seen a few *similar* curl/ssl issues floating around the internet, but I haven't been able to find a solution.

I'm setting up my application to upload a PDF to Dropbox. I've had it working for a few years, but I think with all the SSL security updates lately, something has changed and now it's stopped working.

I'm getting this error message now when trying to run a test:

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Dropbox\Exception_NetworkIO' with message 'Error executing HTTP request: SSL connect error' in /var/web/freelancetrackr.com/public_html/Dropbox/Curl.php:69`

http://freelancetrackr.com/Dropbox/test.php

I'm using the latest version of the PHP SDK API. Running the Dropbox test I get this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing your PHP installation's SSL implementation for a few obvious problems...
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
- Host OS: Linux 2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.x86_64
- PHP version: 5.5.19
- cURL version: 7.19.7
- cURL SSL backend: NSS/3.16.1 Basic ECC
Basic SSL tests
- testAllowed (www.dropbox.com) ....................
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think this will be too few information to isolate the problem. Just a few tips to narrow the problem: try with another target URL, try with another SSL client, try to get more detailed error messages, do a packet capture...

Comment: The Dropbox API did recently drop support for SSLv3 (in favor of TLS). Developers with apps making API calls over SSLv3 were notified via email, but it's possible your email address is out of date or the email went to spam, so I recommend looking into what secure transport protocol (SSLv3, TLSv1. etc.) you are using.

Comment: Greg - thanks for putting me on the right track. The simple answer was that I needed to update my Dropbox PHP SDK version - which changes the SSL to TLS. :)